# Execution Control In C

Tags: c++, time, execution

I was solving a problem where i was asked to output the list of numbers satisfying certain conditions. The score awarded depended upon the size of the output ( as it is a partial marking question). How do i restrict my code to keep outputting the numbers till it does hits the time limit.

Comment: *Maybe* through `SIGALARM`, but your question is absurdly vague.

Comment: search through the forum for making a function execute for a given amount of time using boost::thread or wait() etc., there are many solutions given

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the obvious structure would be something like this:

```
while (current_time < end_time) {
    current_number = *next_number++;
    if (meets_conditions(current_number))
       output(current_number);
}
```